# SQL: optional search by additional index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some data including date:

```
id   action_type     created_date    data
1     action 1      20180405 03:00    ...
2     action 2      20180405 03:01    ...
3     action 1      20180405 02:58    ...
```

I have two separate indices (I can't add another index): by `action_type` and by `created_date`. I need a query that will select all entries with certain `action_type` between certain dates:

```
-- Query 1:
declare @from_date datetime = '20180101 00:00'
        ,@to_date datetime = '20180301 00:00'
        ,@action_type varchar(20) = 'action 1'

select  *
from    my_table
where   created_at between @from_date and @to_date
        and action_type = @action_type
```

I'm using this query and just change variables values in the declaration part. The problem is that I don't have an index that incorporates both date and type, so the query is not efficient, but I can't do anything about that.

However, sometimes I need to run the query for all dates (without the constraint on dates). I don't want to write a different query, so what I'm doing is I'm setting `@from_date = '20010101 00:00'` and `@to_date = getdate()` as I'm sure all dates are greater than Jan 1, 2001.

My questions are:

1 I guess server doesn't "understand" that all data falls in this region and still performs a search by date. Am I right that in this case it'll be more efficient not to run the search by date, as in:

```
select  *
from    my_table
where   action_type = @action_type
```

2 Will the following query eliminate search by date in case `@from_date` is null? I mean, is this more efficient for the case when I don't need to constraint by date, than Query 1?

```
select  *
from    my_table
where   (created_at between @from_date and @to_date or @from_date is null)
        and action_type = @action_type
```

3 Is there any other way to write a query that would incorporate both cases: will search by date if it's not null and won't if it's null; and will be efficient?

Comment: I think your Query should work after you change Year in your from and to date from 2018 to 2001.

Comment: @VedPrakashTiwari It is working now, I just want to make it more efficient: I want to eliminate the unnecessary search by date in case I don't need it

Comment: I think you'd find [**Aaron's article on these type of kitchen sink queries**](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) useful since you are focused on performance.

Comment: Why can't you create more indexes? and are you certain this is not a parameter sniffing issue (as per the link to Aaron Bertrand)

Comment: @scsimon Nice article! And one important thing that they implicitly mention is that I can actually check the execution plan to answer my question:)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid my database is read-only, which means that I'll have to put everything in a temporary table in order to add a new index. In order to evade parameter sniffing I'll need to create a dynamic query, right?

Comment: If it is parameter sniffing that’s one solution but first be sure that it is. I prefer the forced recompile over a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `union all`:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.action_type = @action_type and @from_date is null
union all
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.action_type = @action_type and
      created_at >= @from_date and created_at <= @to_date is null;
```

Each subquery should be evaluated independently.  I think SQL Server is smart enough to recognize that a `NULL` conditions mean no rows are returned.